# Updating listview through fragments

Tags: android, listview, sql-update

here is my problem I have an activity that contains two fragments. Fragment A have a listview and Fragment B is in charge of updating the database now I don't know how to update the datas in listview inside Fragment A right after updating the data in Database from Fragment B. Can you help me and give a sample code for this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Simple. You can make listener and register to your fragment B and the result will be displayed in your Fragment A. Or you should use Event Bus too.

Comment: Have you read the docs http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: thanks for answering guys ill try to understand this sample in docs.

Comment: You can use Broadcast Receiver for this

Answer (score 3):

In this example, FragmentA call notify.

**INotifier**

```
public interface INotifier {
    public void notify(Object data);
}
```

**Utils**

```
public class Utils {
    public static INotifier notifier;
}
```

**FragmentA**

```
public FragmentA extends Fragment {

   public void onCreateView(...) {

   }

   public void inSomeMethod() {
        if (Utils.notifier != null) {
           Utils.notifier.notify(data);
        }
   }
}
```

**FragmentB**

```
public FragmentB extends Fragment implements INotifier {

   public void onCreateView(...) {
       Utils.notifier = this;   
   }

   @Override
   public void notify(Object data) {
       // handle data
   }
}
```