# update textviews on different fragments based on asyntask result

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I've an activity which on create calls an async task.

```
public class Sync extends BaseActivity implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sync);
        CheckForDeviceTask(Sync.this).execute(Constants.DEVICE_ADDRESS);
    }
}
```

Now the result of the async task determines which fragment to load inside the activity which I was able to do. But could not figure how to update the textviews inside the fragments. Please take a look at the onPostExecute() method. After loading a fragment how do I update the TextViews based on the result?

```
public class CheckForDeviceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private static final String TAG = "CheckForDeviceTask";
    public static final int CONNECTED_DEVICE_EXISTS = 1;
    public static final int WAITING_TEMP_PASSWORD = 2;
    private Activity activity;

    // private DialogFragment dialogFragment;

    public CheckForDeviceTask(Activity activity) {
        super();
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // FragmentManager fm = activity.getFragmentManager();
        // dialogFragment = ProgressDialogFragment.newInstance("Saving");
        // dialogFragment.show(fm, "dialog");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        if (GCHUtils.isConnected(activity)) {
            return GCHUtils.httpGet(RestApiPaths.CHECK_FOR_DEVICE
                    + params[0].toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // dialogFragment.dismiss();
        try {
            if (result != null && !result.isEmpty()) {
                Map<String, Object> resultMap = MapUtility.jsonToMap(result);
                if (resultMap != null && !resultMap.isEmpty()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, resultMap.get("status").toString());
                    FragmentManager fm;
                    FragmentTransaction ft;
                    if (Boolean.valueOf(resultMap.get("status").toString())) {
                        int type = Integer.valueOf(resultMap.get("type")
                                .toString());
                        switch (type) {
                        case CONNECTED_DEVICE_EXISTS: {
                            GCHConnectedFragment connectedGCHFragment = new GCHConnectedFragment();
                            fm = activity.getFragmentManager();
                            ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                            ft.replace(R.id.layoutToReplace,
                                    connectedGCHFragment);
                            ft.commit();
                            String email = resultMap.get("emailId").toString();
                            String name = resultMap.get("name").toString();
                            // now I need to update two TextViews in GCHConnectedFragment based with these values  
                        }
                            break;
                        case WAITING_TEMP_PASSWORD: {

                            TempPasswordFragment tempPasswordFragment = new TempPasswordFragment();
                            fm = activity.getFragmentManager();
                            ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                            ft.replace(R.id.layoutToReplace,
                                    tempPasswordFragment);
                            ft.commit();
                            String tempPassword = resultMap.get("tempPassword")
                                    .toString(); // TODO: encrypt
                            String expiryDate = resultMap.get("expiryDate")
                                    .toString();
//                          now I need to update two TextViews in tempPasswordFragment based with these values
                        }
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        // TODO: init UI with connect with GCH option
                        ConnectGCHFragment connectGCHFragment = new ConnectGCHFragment();
                        fm = activity.getFragmentManager();
                        ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                        ft.replace(R.id.layoutToReplace, connectGCHFragment);
                        ft.commit();
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can call any method from the fragment just like you call from any other class's object. Create the required method in the fragment and call it in your onPostExecute() method.

Comment: use sharedPreference to store value and get it back when you want to display.

Comment: Try out this one may be it will help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35238587/2183890)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First put the data you get eg email and name, in a bundle and send the bundle as arguments to the destination Fragment,as shown below:-

```
          `Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("email ", email );
            bundle.putBoolean("name", name);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);`
```

In the destination Fragment get the data as follows:

```
                  `String email=getArguments().getString("email");
                   String name=getArguments().getString("name");`
```