# How to update view in Fragment from child fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

[image]

Have two fragments A and B, Fragment A has Textview and Fragment B has edittext and button.
Click on submit in FragmentB need to update textview in FragmentA with Edittext text.

How to do communication between fragment?

Comment: try invalidate Textview in Fragment with callback.

Comment: There are 2 possibilities either you can use interface between those fragments or you can use Eventbus library which allows you to create local events and events listener for that.
if you need more on eventbus let me know.

Comment: You have to add a listener and look at this http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: As @androidnoobdev said you can either use Interface or SharedPrefrences to update the view. Here is the simple implementation of interface [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35238587/2183890)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

n this example, FragmentA call notify. 
INotifier

```
public interface INotifier {
    public void notify(Object data);
}
```

Utils

```
public class Utils {
    public static INotifier notifier;
}
```

FragmentA

```
public FragmentA extends Fragment {

   public void onCreateView(...) {

   }

   public void inSomeMethod() {
        if (Utils.notifier != null) {
           Utils.notifier.notify(data);
        }
   }
}
```

FragmentB

```
public FragmentB extends Fragment implements INotifier {

   public void onCreateView(...) {
       Utils.notifier = this;   
   }

   @Override
   public void notify(Object data) {
       // handle data
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to interact the activity first which will interact the second fragment. and also read this article on how to do it.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Answer (score 0):

The communication between `Fragments` is done usinng `Listeners`. When you want to update fragment, use the listener to tell the `MainActivity` to update the second fragment as recommended by Google http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html. Create the interface in `Fragment` and Implement this in `Activity`

**Listener in Fragment**

```
public interface FragmentUpdateInterface {
        void updateFragment(String newText);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (FragmentUpdateInterface ) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement FragmentUpdateListener");
    }
}

@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Send the event to the host activity
        mCallback.updateFragment("New Text");
    }
```

**MainActivity**
Implement fragment in `MainActivity`  as

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements MyFragment.FragmentUpdateListener{

public void updateFragment(String newText) {
OtherFragment otherFrag = (OtherFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.other_fragment);

        if (otherFrag != null) {
            otherFrag.updateFragment(newText);
        } else {
            // Otherwise, we're in the one-pane layout and must swap frags...

            // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
            OtherFragment otherFrag = new OtherFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
            otherFrag.setArguments(args);

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, otherFrag);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**

You can also use `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance().sendBroadcast()` to notify to the other fragment as well.

Comment: its giving cyclic inheritance issue

Comment: Are you using any other interface which is being implemented in Fragment?

Comment: yes, am using tab change listners...check my answer

Comment: Yes that's an issue. Fragment and activity both are depending on each other.

Comment: ok check implemented some code but its not updating first call after its working fine