# Android shared element transition between two list items

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I have two activities. Both contains a recycler view. I want to switch from `activity1` to `activity2` with a shared element transition. Is it possible? As far as I know i cant get reference of the destination element before `onBindViewHolder()`. Is there anyway to get around it ?

Comment: Can you explain what the 'shared element transition' is?

Comment: Use interfaces [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35238587/2183890)

Comment: @Diyoda I was talking about material shared element transition https://guides.codepath.com/android/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition

Comment: Way to go @AKSiddique, post it as answer and I shall mark it as solution.

Comment: @dumb_terminal instead of posting duplicate answer, if the link is useful for you then upvote the answer.